# Finding whether the slide is skipped or not using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I want to check among the slides, whether a slide is skipped or not?

I have referred the API as well as slide service, but I couldn't find a way to determine the skipped slide.

How do I write a custom code `slide.isSkipped()` which will return true if skipped or false if not?

Comment: This isnt currently exposed. You can file a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features)! thanks!