# How to tell if a slide is "skipped" in Google Slides with Google Apps Script or API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-apps-script-addon, google-slides

In Google Slides, it's possible to set a slide to be "skipped" in presentation mode (as described [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1694830?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)).

However, the automated page numbering still includes skipped slides (meaning that in presentation mode, if slide `4` is skipped, the slide numbering jumps straight from `3` to `5`).

I want to use Google Apps Script to generate my own slide numbers so only non-skipped slides are counted. But I don't know how to check if a slide is marked as "skipped."

Here's what I have in mind:

```
function genSlideNumbers() {
  var preso = SlidesApp.openById('PRESENTATION_ID');
  var slides = preso.getSlides()
  var slide_num = 1
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slide = slides[i]
    if ( /* ?? slide is "skipped" ?? */ ) {
      slides[i].insertTextBox(slide_num);
      slide_num++;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Edit: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878119/how-to-skip-slides-in-google-slides-with-google-apps-script) because I'm not asking how to skip a slide; I'm asking if there's any way to tell if a slide is skipped.

Comment: Did you review the existing questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878119/how-to-skip-slides-in-google-slides-with-google-apps-script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740005/finding-whether-the-slide-is-skipped-or-not-using-gas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip slides in Google Slides with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878119/how-to-skip-slides-in-google-slides-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks, but yes, I did see that question. I'm not asking how to skip a slide; I'm asking if there's any way to tell if a slide is skipped. Related, but not the same.

Comment: If the API has no support (what that answer says) then you can't do anything with that property.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice [the second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740005/finding-whether-the-slide-is-skipped-or-not-using-gas) in the first comment. I had missed that question indeed. This issue is tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70530893).

Answer (score 2):

Update: There is now a method [`slide.isSkipped()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#isskipped) which determines if the slide is marked as skipped.  (Also [`slide.setSkipped()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#setskippedisskipped) to set whether the slide will be skipped.)

Answer (score 1):

As of 10/25/2019 there is no API access to the **Skip Slide** flag in the [Slide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide) or [Presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation) classes. Which means there's no method (using only Apps Script) to determine which slides to skip.

Ideally, there would be  `slide.getSkip()` and `slide.setSkip()` methods, but they don't currently exist. You can [request them here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112692346).